# IDXGIInfoQueue is not defined when using MinGW from MSYS2

Tags: c++, g++

This works on both MSVC and Clang. But on MinGW I keep getting the following error:

```
error: 'IDXGIInfoQueue' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'ID3D11InfoQueue'?
17 |   ComRef<IDXGIInfoQueue> m_DxgiInfoQueue = nullptr;
```

I have checked that I have included the `<dxgidebug.h>` header file. What might be happening here?

I just need suggestions as to how to approach debugging this problem. I probably haven't provided enough information, so I will provide any more information that is needed.

Any help is appreciated.